# Conference proceedings and talks on a CV?

Tags: conference, cv, presentation

I come from a multidisciplinary background, mostly biostatistics and bioinformatics. I'm currently updating my CV to apply for a post doc and I'm wondering how do people include conference proceedings and invited talks in a CV.

In my case, I have two type of abstracts: 
- peer-reviewed conference proceedings which are published in journals,
- peer-reviewed abstracts accepted in national or smaller conferences which aren't published.

Should I make a distinction between these two types of abstracts? How do you separate abstracts selected for an oral comunication and/or poster and invited talks?

I used to have a section named **Conference contribution** and three subsections **Invited talk**, **Oral communication** and **Poster** but I'm not sure about this format and I'm wondering whether it's relevant to add this information or if I should filter more. Also, do people include all abstracts or only the first author?

Comment: I would not include my presentations in my CV, but I keep only the most important things (CV should be around 2 to 3 pages). Your potential employer won't read everything but only what he is interested in (for sure not your presentations). You can add a link at the end of your CV referring to your complete CV (which can be a web page). For publications, you could put your 3 best papers under a section named: Selected Publications

Comment: @Younes the OP is applying for a postdoc so a complete CV would be appropriate.

Comment: @anonymous I am sure that my professor does not spend one second to check the list of talks. A postdoc is not different than any other position. Even publications, one would mention the number of his publications but one puts the best of what he published (What if the candidate published 30 articles in proceedings? -which happens often-). The professor is as any other employer, is interested not only in research but also the ability to work in a group, solving problems, working under hard circumstances. Hence, the CV should cover everything but rationally.

Comment: @Younes That would be correct for a *short* CV, but generally a CV is intended to be a *complete* listing of your productivity as an academic. You will see postings that will indicate if a short version is preferred and there may be some regional differences, but if you published thirty articles, you should have thirty articles listed on your CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little bit of variation depending upon the discipline, but generally the convention is along the lines of the following:

> **CONFERENCE PROCEEDINGS**
>
> **Invited Talks**
>
> Unsolicited presentations (ex. keynotes) where you are invited by the organizers.
>
> **Papers**
>
> Complete manuscripts that are published in proceedings and indexed by relevant databases.
>
> **Abstracts**
>
> Short (i.e., 250 words) or possibly extended abstracts intended to describe the talk.
>
> **Posters**
>
> Any poster presentations, these may be eliminated by senior scholars.

Generally the rule of thumb is that the section is organized by most prestigious (i.e., invited talks) to least prestigious (i.e., posters). When applying for an academic position this section should be as complete as possible as well. Additionally, it may include notation indicating you are the presenter if you are not the first author.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So you would include any poster, including the ones you didn't present but you're a co-author or only the ones you presented?

Comment: @psoares Early career, listing everything makes sense, as you advance in your career you might limit it just the you presented and have something noting "Selected Posters." Be sure to indicate the ones you presented though.